# Define a method in DSLD (Parameter types)

Tags: eclipse, groovy, dsl, dsld

I already have defined a DSL in Groovy. Now I'm working on the Eclipse integration so that I have auto completion and other fancy stuff.

This doesn't work:

```
method name:"myMethod", params : [param1: MyClass]
```

This works:

```
method name:"myMethod", params : [param1: java.util.Random]
```

How can I use MyClass as a type for one of my parameters?

MyClass is a Groovy class in the normal package tree. I have tried it with another classes and interfaces which are defined in the DSDL itself. Then it works.

Comment: Have you tried the fully qualified name for `MyClass`, ie: `my.package.MyClass`

Comment: Yes, I have tried it, but it doesn't work, neither with a full qualified name nor with an import statement and the simple name.

Comment: Have you tried in a String?  `method name:"myMethod", params : [param1: "my.package.MyClass"]`?

Comment: @tim_yates: Qualified name within a String works.

Comment: Cool, added as an answer (and made to look like I knew it all along) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to put the fully qualified class name as a String as shown a [page or so down from here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/DSL+Descriptors+for+Groovy-Eclipse#DSLDescriptorsforGroovy-Eclipse-NewFeaturesinGroovy-Eclipse2.5.2)

So:

```
method name:"myMethod", params : [param1: MyClass]
```

Should be:

```
method name:"myMethod", params : [param1: "my.package.MyClass"]
```